# delete everything after specified character

Tags: vb.net

I use this code to delete certain words before the letter or word that I put, but it does not work with all texts, only the first line.
How do I make this code work on all texts in TextBox1

[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim list As String = TextBox1.Text
       

        Dim substring As String = list.Remove(list.IndexOf(txtafter.Text) + 1)

       
        TextBox2.Text = substring

    End Sub
```

I use this code to delete certain words before the letter or word that I put, but it does not work with all texts, only the first line.

Comment: What value does Textbox1.Text actually contain? You need to split on newline first and handle the lines separately

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, no need to split explicitly. The `Lines` property does it for you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Even better!

Answer (score 3):

The `Text` of the control is a single `String` containing the entire text. It's not that your code is only working on one line. It's that it's working on a single `String`. If you want to operate on each line individually then you need to get each line individually. The obvious way to do that is to use the `Lines` property, which returns an array containing the lines as elements. Note that it generates a new array every time, so changes you make to that array will not affect the source control.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines

    For i = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim line = lines(i)

        lines(i) = line.Remove(line.IndexOf(txtafter.Text) + 1)
    Next

    TextBox2.Lines = lines
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted my project from textbox.text to listbox and i fine now .. Thanks for Hans Keﬆing and Thank you jmcilhinney For your code sure i will use this in someday. [image]

Comment: A `ListBox` and a `TextBox` are fairly different so you shouldn't switch just so that you can get access to the lines of text as items. If a `ListBox` provides more appropriate functionality in general then that's fine, but don't use a dodgy workaround when a simple solution exists.